# Mongoose Schema Design approach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am new to NoSql databases. I am trying to build a project and stuck with the approach of whether to choose sql databases or NoSql Databases for the project.

The requirements of my project are a legal firm would have many clients and each client can have different matter Type such as Immigration, Conveyancing, Family and etc and each MatterType can also have different fields which are never constant and they can fairly change in future.

Due to this nature I thought Nosql databases might be a good choice as they are document based and I can add any new fields to the document structure instead of always adding new columns to a sql data table dynamically which is not a good approach ( atleast i think)

Can anyone please kindly suggest me or refer me to an article which can assist me in deciding my approach

To give my clarity into my question let me explain with an example

For a client name xyz and matterType Immigration I can have fields such as firstName,lastName,Dob at this moment but later on for the same client I might have to add Dependants and their details

For a client name def and matterType conveyancing I would have different fields but those fields should also be added dynamically depending on the matter Type

Thank you in advance

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to look into postgres sql if you are expecting large datasets. It offers the advantages of no sql databases such as support for key value pair and also keeping a rigid data structure like sql databases. Following are links to a few articles which may help you decide which approach to choose:

[NoSql vs Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-vs-sql)

[postgres vs mongodb](http://www.aptuz.com/blog/is-postgres-nosql-database-better-than-mongodb/)

Comment: Thank you for the response Gaurav but the links are not working

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't only consider this feature in other to decide between NoSql or RBMDS.

In fact, this flexibility sounds very good, but it might be dangerous, once systems tend to raise, then things can get out of hand.

I have a system where I use MongoDB, but even though, I decided creating a schema for my collections.

I would suggest you finish modeling, then after that, conclude if it's really necessary to use NoSql.